# Best configuration of Auto Scaling Group for Rails application deployed using NGINX and Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, load-balancing, puma, aws-auto-scaling

I am using the Amazon Auto Scaling group for Rails application deployed on an EC2 instance using NGINX and Puma. I am facing some challenges with the configuring of the Auto Scaling policy.

I am using r5.xlarge for the main instance that is hosting my corn jobs and r5.large for the autoscaling instance. My current scaling trigger is defined on the 50% CPU but apparently, that does not work due to the following reasons

1. Since the main instance has 4 CPUs the overall consumption did not hit 50% unless there is some corn job running that is consuming all resources.
2. Even if the CPU will hit 50% the startup time of rails application is 30-40 seconds and in the meantime, all requests received by the server returns 503.
3. If the CPU consumption is less than 50% but the system receives a lot of concurrent requests it does not start a new instance and either start returning 503 or the response time increases significantly.

I have tried changing the auto-scaling group from CPU consumption to the number of requests but the start time issue of instance still prevails and sometimes it starts a new instance when it is not even needed.

Have you ever faced any such issue with Rails deployment, anything that you thinks worked for your out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

We are running Ruby application with PUMA in ECS Tasks, but should be quite the same problematic that with EC2.

Since Ruby is single threaded, your Ruby Process running your PUMA server is only going to use one CPU at a time. If you have 4 CPU, I imagine one PUMA process will never manage to saturate more than 25% of the overall machine.

Note: Also have a look at your configuration regarding the number of PUMA Threads. This is also critical to configure, since you are doing auto-scaling, your application NEED to be able to saturate the CPU it's using, to be able to kick in. With too few Puma Thread it will not be the case, with too much your application will become unstable, this is something to fine tune.

Recommendation:

1. Run one PUMA process per CPU you have available with the EC2 class you have chosen, each PUMA server listening on a different port, have your load-balancer manage that. This should allow your machine to reach potentially 100% CPU during saturation (in theory), allowing auto-scaling base on CPU to work
2. Preferred solution: Pick smaller machines, with 1 CPU, so you only need to run one PUMA server per machine.

From my experience with ECS, Ruby and other single threaded languages should not use more than 1 (v)CPU machines, and you should instead really on heavy horizontal scaling if necessary (some of our service are running 50x ECS instances).

Hope this helps.